# How to check to make sure there are no repeats when generating 6 random numbers?

Tags: c, arrays, random, numbers

I can get the random numbers into an array but I can't figure out how to check to make sure that they aren't repeating. I print out the code but there are no numbers in the array (prints out nothing).

```
//puts random numbers into an array
i = 0, j = 0;
srand(time(NULL));
for (i = 0; i < arrSize; i++)
{
  randArr[i] = randNums(1,50);
}

i = 0;
for(i = 0; i < arrSize; i++)
{
  printf("%d ", randArr[i]);
}

printf("\n\n");

//checks to make sure there are no duplicates
i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, temp = 0;
for (i = 0; i < arrSize; i++)
{
  for (j = 1; j <= arrSize;)
  {
    if (randArr[j] == randArr[i])
    {
      for (k = j; k <= arrSize; k++)
      {
        temp = randNums(1,50);
        randArr[k + 1] = temp;
      }
      arrSize--;
    }
    else
      j++;
  }
}

//generates random numbers between the inputed max and min
int randNums(int min, int max)
{
  int result = 0, low = 0, high = 0;
  if (min < max)
  {
    low = min;
    high = max + 1;
  }
  else
  {
    low = max + 1;
    high = min;
  }
  result = (rand() % (high - low)) + low;
  return (result);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should give a minimal complete and verifiable example. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for a guide. It should include all declarations and your main.

Comment: @AlainMerigot This is just a sliver of my code because the other part doesnt affect this part at all

Comment: This is generally an algorithmic problem and has many different solutions with different trade-offs. You will find many different approaches on the internet, just to link _some_ source here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-duplicates-in-on-time-and-constant-extra-space/

Comment: I think using a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution recurrence and then randomly permute the values is probably the fastest, but one could sort and re-roll if two values intersect.

Comment: I like that idea by @Neil

Comment: One could stick the uniform values into a hash set to test whether the next value should be rejected; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling.

Answer (score 1):

Beware! There are many different solutions to this problem and they all have one or another downside. If I was to quickly implement it, I would go for something like this (without too much `C`-magic going on):

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define SIZE (30)
#define RAND_MIN (1)
#define RAND_MAX (50)

static int randNums(int min, int max) {
  // ...
}

int main(void) {
  (void) srand(time(NULL));
  int arr[SIZE];
  int used = 0;
  while (used < SIZE) {
    int  num    = randNums(RAND_MIN, RAND_MAX);
    bool exists = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < used; ++i) {
      if (arr[i] == num)
        exists = true;
    }
    if (exists == false)
      arr[used++] = num;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
    (void) printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I hope it helps a bit :)

Comment: Please also note that this creates an **endless loop** if there are less numbers in `randNums()` than `SIZE`; if that was more than just playing around with ideas, you would definitely want to verify that upfront.

Comment: `else {
    low  = max + 1;
    high = min;
  }` appears mixed up.  I suspect you want `else {
    low  = max;
    high = min + 1;
  }`    Also trouble with `randNums(some_int, INT_MAX)` and any case where mathematically  `max - min > INT_MAX`

Comment: You are right of course; used that part "as is" from sarah since the question was about unique numbers, not about random number generation.

Answer (score 0):

Like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54299158/2472827), you can do [rejection sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling), but the uniform distribution of a fixed number of samples is perfect for a very simple hash set. (Though the asymptotic runtime might be irrelevant for `n=6`.)

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* (s)rand */
#include <stdio.h>  /* printf */
#include <time.h>   /* clock */
#include <assert.h> /* assert */

/* Double-pointers are confusing. */
struct Reference { int *ref; };

/* Simple fixed hash set. */
static struct Reference bins[256];
static int nums[6];
static const size_t no_bins = sizeof bins / sizeof *bins,
    no_nums = sizeof nums / sizeof *nums;
static size_t count_num;

/* Uniformly distributed numbers are great for hashing, but possibly clump
 together under linear probing. */
static size_t hash(const int n) { return ((size_t)n * 21) % no_bins; }

/* Linear probing. */
static struct Reference *probe(const int n) {
    size_t bin_index;
    struct Reference *bin;
    assert(sizeof bins > sizeof nums);
    for(bin_index = hash(n); bin = bins + bin_index,
        bin->ref && *bin->ref != n; bin_index = (bin_index + 1) % no_bins);
    return bin;
}

/* Return whether it's a new value. */
static int put_in_set(const int n) {
    struct Reference *bin = probe(n);
    int *num;
    assert(count_num < no_nums);
    if(bin->ref) return 0; /* Already in hash. */
    num = nums + count_num++;
    *num = n;
    bin->ref = num;
    return 1;
}

/* http://c-faq.com/lib/randrange.html */
static int rand_range(const unsigned n) {
    unsigned int x = (RAND_MAX + 1u) / n;
    unsigned int y = x * n;
    unsigned int r;
    assert(n > 0);
    do {
        r = rand();
    } while(r >= y);
    return r / x;
}

/* Generates random numbers between the inputed max and min without
 repetition; [min, max] inclusive. */
static int unique_uniform(const int min, const int max) {
    int n;
    assert(min <= max && (size_t)(max - min) >= count_num);
    do { n = rand_range(max - min + 1) + min; } while(!put_in_set(n));
    return n;
}

int main(void) {
    int n = 6;
    srand((int)clock()), rand(); /* My computer always picks the same first? */
    while(n--) { printf("%d\n", unique_uniform(1, 50)); }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

However, if the numbers are densely packed, (eg, `unique_uniform(1, 6)`,) it's going to reject a lot of numbers. Another solution is to take a [Poisson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) distributed numbers as a running sum, (recurrence `T(n+1)=T(n)+\mu_{n+1}`,) where the expected value is the range of numbers divided by the total samples, then take a [random permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_permutation).